# redirecting a new page on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to redirect to a new page in same directory on button click in a page.

directory structure: main(folder) --> index.html, home.html

index.html has login section on button click i want the page to go to home.html.

```
$('#login').click( function() {         
        var user = $("#user").val(); 
        var pass = $("#pass").val(); 
        if(user == "xyz" && pass =="testing1"){
        location.href('home.html');
        }else{alert("invalid credits")}
    });
```

Comment: just change to `location.href = 'home.html'`

Comment: window.location = 'home.html';

Comment: @Siri Sireesha: just to mention..i hope you are not storing userNames and passwords in javascript files.. because everybody can read them

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location = window.location.href.replace("index.html","home.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
window.location = "put url here"
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.location.href('home.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#login').click(function(){
  ...........
  document.location.href='the_link_to_go_to.html';
})
```

`window.location.replace(...)` will best simulate an HTTP redirect

If you want to simulate an HTTP redirect, use `location.replace`.

```
window.location.href = 'the_link';
window.location.replace("the_link");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use  `window.location.href`

```
window.location.href='home.html'
```